# Ajax file upload script overwrites my session variables PHP

Tags: php, ajax

Below is the script that my ajax file uploader uses. The uploader itself works fine but i need a method of storing the files that are uploaded and I am using session variables. The problem is if I upload more than one file the first session variable is being overwritten each time i upload a file and so i end up with only $_SESSION['hamhamham'] containing data. Can someone tell me what i am doing wrong here? Thanks in advance

```
session_start();

$uploaddir = '../uploads/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . date() .time() . basename($_FILES['myfile']['name']);


/* $_SESSION['hamhamham'] = $uploadfile; */

$full = false;

if(isset($_SESSION['hamhamham'])){ 

    if(isset($_SESSION['hohoho'])){ 

        if(isset($_SESSION['workforme'])){ 

            if(isset($_SESSION['sweet'])){ 

                $full = true;

            }else{
                $_SESSION['sweet'] = $uploadfile;
            }

        }else{
            $_SESSION['workforme'] = $uploadfile;
        }

    }else{
        $_SESSION['hohoho'] = $uploadfile;
    }

}else{
    $_SESSION['hamhamham'] = $uploadfile;
}

if($full==false){
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
      echo "success";
    } else {
      // WARNING! DO NOT USE "FALSE" STRING AS A RESPONSE!
      // Otherwise onSubmit event will not be fired
      echo "error";
    }
}else{
    echo "too many files uploaded";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array

```
$_SESSION['files'][] = $uploadFile;
```

To Access

```
foreach($_SESSION['files'] as $file_name)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate! I owe you one virtual beer!